# Finding two functions for limits

Tags: limits, functions

So here is the question I was asked to solve.

Find an example of two functions $f$ and $g$, defined everywhere on $(0,\infty)$ such that:

$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)}$ does not exist but:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)g(x) = 1 $$

I can easily think of functions that does not exist as infinity. I'm having a really hard time finding a function that the product of both would equal 1 though.

Any hints?

Comment: By the way $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{x^4}$ do have a limit as $x\to\infty$ and that limit is $0$ in both cases.

Comment: Yeah I realized my error. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! @Mario G.

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(x):=\cos(x)+2$ and $g(x):=\frac{1}{f(x)}$

Comment: THat's perfect! I can't believe I didn't think of that!!

Comment: Wait!!! The second limit is 0 is it not?

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty No. it oscillating on (1/3,1).

Comment: No, the second limit doesn't exist because the denominator oscillates between $1$ and $3$.

Comment: Ahh yes, squeeze theorem.

Comment: Squeeze Theorem?!

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty In fact any positive [oscillation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_%28mathematics%29) $f$ that $\limsup_{x\to\inf}{f(x)} \neq \liminf_{x\to\inf}{f(x)}$ will work. The cases $\lim_{x\to\inf}(f(x))=\inf,\lim_{x\to\inf}(g(x))=\inf$ will not work, since $\inf*\inf=\inf$

Comment: @guest: Sorry my mistake. I swear my brain is dead today. I usually do Differential equations not single variable calculus, which I haven't done in a while.